# Ambulance LEGO Sets

Tags: lego-group, vehicle

I am looking for an ambulance LEGO set as I have police and fire. 
Doing some research it looks like LEGO currently provides no ambulance vans/trucks and have only had a few in the past.

Are there ambulances in the LEGO line that are coming in the future or that are out right now? Looking on eBay only returned a few results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't an ambulance slated for release in 2017, and there hasn't been one available since [4431](http://brickset.com/sets/4431-1/Ambulance) in 2012:

[image: 4431]

This set can be picked up currently for as little as $30 used on [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4431-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D) or eBay.

Comment: Considering that minifigs often go for $10 each it is like you're getting the ambulance free.  :)